# Bulk Update in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkupdate

Here is the scenario.

I am updating multiple records in a table based on join condition from a different table. I would like to execute a SP as and when there is an update. Here is the SQL I am using for the update.

```
 Update ep
  Set ep.AddressEMail = mail
 FROM SampleTable Samp
  Inner Join Emp ec 
 On ec.EecEmpNo = Samp.employeeid
  Inner Join Emp ep
 on ep.EEID = ec.EecEEID
  Where ep.AddressEMail <> mail
```

I would like to call the following SP for every update thats happening.

```
EXEC dbo.AddQuickEvent
```

Do I have to change my above SQL to loop through every record and execute the SP (exec dbo.AddQuickEvent) that is required or is there any other way to execute the other stored procedure when there is an update to the row.

Answer (score 2):

An update is a set based operation so it is probably best not to loop through records and call a SP for each record as that would be horribly inefficient.

A better option might be to do whatever it is you are trying to do in 'AddQuickEvent' in a trigger on the table and operate on the set of updated records.

When operating in SQL it is almost always better to think in terms of set operations rather than looping and processing each record individually.

Comment: Thanks a lot mike for your valuable suggestion. If I am not concerned about performace, looping through cursor would be an option?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the AddQuickEvent? Looping is always an option, just almost always not the best one.

Comment: There are quite few things happening in that procedure but I could always copy the same code into trigger

Comment: If you can do those things in a set based operation, that would be better. A trigger executes for the set of updated rows, not a single row.